# Audio recording in android with particular time interval

Tags: android, timer, audio-recording

I have two method in my activity one is `setOnClickListener()` and other is `setOnLongClickListener()`
For the same button which used to start audio recording.

Now i don't know how to use condition, if i use `setOnClickListener()`  then recording should start for 1 minute and stop automatically, and if i use `setOnLongClickListener()` then recording start for 2 minute and then stop automatically.

```
buttonStart.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Record_Audio.this,
                    "Start Recording With LongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            enableButtons(true);
            startRecording();
            return true;
        }
    });


private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStart: {
            Toast.makeText(Record_Audio.this, "Start Recording",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            enableButtons(true);
            startRecording();
            break;
        }
}
});

private void startRecording() {
    displayAlertDialog();
}


private void displayAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Record_Audio.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("Would you Like to save your Recording");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Audio Name");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.save_icon);

    final EditText editTextAudioName = new EditText(Record_Audio.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    editTextAudioName.setLayoutParams(lp);
    alertDialog.setView(editTextAudioName);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Code.audioName = editTextAudioName.getText().toString()
                            .trim();

                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
                    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
                    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
                    try {
                        recorder.prepare();
                        recorder.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    myChronometer.start();
                }
            });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I know i have to use `setMaxDuration` for particular time interval, but i don't know how to use with this two method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Due to the unpredictable delay of the audio APIs, if I wanted a recording of a precise length I'd be tempted to have the recording cut off after (desired seconds) worth of data has been received.  You might end up collecting an integral number of buffers and throwing away whatever portion of the last one you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow the MediaRecorder Api is not good way to use record audio.Use the AudioRecorder API.

Let me explain

1.This is class for recording audio

public class Taukyrecorder {

```
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".mp3";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "/'/'";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private int bufferSize = 0;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
public static boolean isRecording = false;
int numCrossing, p;

public int frequency;

int blockSize = 3500;
private Context mcontext;



public static String final_sound_path = null;

Handler handler;

RecorderListener mylistener;

public Taukyrecorder(Context cntxt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mcontext = cntxt;

    // Log.i("Recorder", "helllllo");

    InitRecord();

}

public void RegisterListener(RecorderListener listener) {

    this.mylistener = listener;
}

public void InitRecord()
{
    handler = new Handler();

    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    recorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(
            new OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }, handler);

}

// Get the file for saving sound into the folder
public File GetFileTOwriteSound() {
    File tempPicFile = null;
    String ext_storage_state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    File mediaStorage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/TAUKY/SOUNDS");
    if (ext_storage_state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        if (!mediaStorage.exists()) {
            mediaStorage.mkdirs();
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        tempPicFile = new File(mediaStorage.getPath() + File.separator
                + "SOUND_" + timeStamp + ".mp3");

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(mcontext, "NO SDCARD MOUNTED", 1).show();

    }
    return tempPicFile;
}

private String getTempFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

    if (tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete();

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
}

public void startRecording() {


    //InitRecord();

    recorder.startRecording();

    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            writedataToFile();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
}

private void writedataToFile() {
    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int read = 0;

    short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
    double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];


    if (null != os) {
        while (isRecording) {

            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                try {
                    os.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //int bufferReadResult = recorder.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);



                //byte[] bData= {};
                short[] sData= new short[data.length/2];
                // to turn bytes to shorts as either big endian or little endian. 
                ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(sData);




                for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < read; i++) {
                    toTransform[i] = sData[i] / 32768.0; 
                }



                mylistener.Updatevalues(toTransform);

            }
        }

        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void stopRecording() {
    String getfilename = GetFileTOwriteSound().getAbsolutePath();
    final_sound_path = getfilename;
    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }

    copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getfilename);
    deleteTempFile();
}

private void deleteTempFile() {
    File file = new File(getTempFilename());

    file.delete();
}

private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
    int channels = 2;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

        // /AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

        while (in.read(data) != -1) {
            out.write(data);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate)
        throws IOException {

    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1; // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}
```

}

Start and stop the record

**MainActivity**

```
TaukkyRecordr taukyrecorder=new Taukyrecorder(mcontext);

taukyrecorder.startRecording();

//For stop
taukyrecorder.stopRecording();
```

If you want stop automatically after few second please create one thread.

```
public class StopRecord extends Thread {
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                taukyrecorder.stopRecording();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Then call the thread using handler

```
Handker mhandler=new Handeler;

mhandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);//put your secodn here
```