# Android: Audio Recorder - save recording after 1 hour

Tags: android, timer, audio-recording

I am new to android development. I have created an audio recording app which stores recording to a file to sdcard. This works fine.

Now what I want to do is save the recording file if recorder has recorded for at least 60 mins else discard and reset recorder.

I have tried all possible options of media recorder, but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20351198/5545429